# Async: false not working on $http call in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, http

```
 $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: rootUrl + '/api/account/login',
            async: false,
            data: loginRequest,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            }
        }).success(function (response) {.
.
.
.
.
```

I have tried above code. But async false is not working. Why? but if i use jquery , then it's working

Have you any idea for this? how can i stop asyn call in http method??

Comment: Is it even supported, did you see it in angularjs [$http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)? Why do you want to do `async:false` anyways?

Comment: I want to call success function code before call next line of the ajax method codes

Comment: The `async` flag is hardcoded in angular source code, see: [httpBackend.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.21/src/ng/httpBackend.js#L64), the third argument of `xhr.open()`.

Comment: @user256103 You need to use promise pattern.. rather than trying to make your code synchronous... `$http(...).then(returnobjectfromsuccesscallback,failurecallback).then(runyoursubsequentcode)` . `async:false` is mostly (i have seen) a hack to support a bad design and you should try not to even think about it during the design...